# Apply a styling on multiple items depending on Boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the style of the bars in each area(12 in total), so that when I get a 1==true(green color) and if I get a 0==false(red color), that will change the color of a bar depending on what I get from the back-end.

I can't get my head around what would be the most straightforward way on doing this.

this is what I have so far:

```
function createPeg(name, checkActive ){

  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);


}

const allPegs = [
  createPeg('peg-1',  pegActive["one"] == 0),
  createPeg('peg-2', pegActive["two"]== 1),
  createPeg('peg-3',  pegActive["three"] ==1),
  createPeg('peg-4',  pegActive["four"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-5',  pegActive["five"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-6',pegActive["six"]== 1),
  createPeg('peg-7', pegActive["seven"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-8',  pegActive["eight"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-9',  pegActive["nine"] ==0),
  createPeg('peg-10', pegActive["ten"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-11',  pegActive["eleven"] == 1),
  createPeg('peg-12',  pegActive["twelve"] == 1),
];


uiProgressBarif(allPegs == 1){
 .style.background="green";

}else if(allPegs == 0){
uiProgressBar.style.background="red";
}
//to test is working
else{
 uiProgressBar.style.background="blue";
}
}
```

css:

```
peg-1-bar-fill{
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="peg-wrapper">
  <div class="peg-name-1">
          <h4>1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="peg-1-start-time total-time">
          <p class="label-2">Length:</p>
          <span id="total-time-1">-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="peg-1-bar">
          <div class="peg-1-bar-fill">
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a ternary operator? They are shorthand for a simple if statement.

`foo === bar ? doThisWhenTrue() : doThisWhenFalse();`

You may be able to determine each of the classnames inline with ternaries.